# Add shortcut to .NET 6 exe in Visual Studio Installer Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-installer

I followed [this guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022) on creating an installer project for a couple of .NET 6 projects, and everything worked fine except I'm struggling to get a shortcut into the start menu.

The way it's supposed to be done, as far as I understand, is to create a shortcut in `User's Programs Menu` that then points to the `Primary output from ...` entry in `Application Folder`, but according to Microsoft, instead of using the primary output I should use `Publish items` for .NET Core projects, so what should I then do for shortcuts?

I tried creating a primary output anyway, and then a shortcut to it, but it didn't work.

This is what my Application Folder looks like right now:

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Installer Project]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was to **build the installer** project, then suddenly I was able to add a new shortcut in `User's Programs Menu` that targeted my WPF `Publish Items` action, and after installation the shortcut finally appeared in my start menu.

What threw me off was the fact that `Primary output` types were always visible when adding shortcuts, so I thought the tool filtered them out because they were incompatible.

My publish actions do have red lines now under them, and I have no idea what they mean, but the installer and shortcut work.

The last thing I needed was "regular shortcuts", not those advertised ones that don't point to the installed EXE, to do that I had to download [this vbs script](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/WiXInstaller/blob/master/Source/WiRunSQL.vbs) to my installer project root dir and run it in the installer's post-build event like so (properties panel on bottom-right):

```
cscript //nologo "$(ProjectDir)WiRunSql.vbs" "$(BuiltOuputPath)" "INSERT INTO Property(Property, Value) VALUES ('DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS', '1')"
```

Finally everything works!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Do not create "Primary output". Instead, create shortcut of "Publish Items from YourApp (Active)" then move that shortcut to "User's Programs Menu" and/or "User's Desktop".

This worked for me .NET 6, Windows Forms application.